# SQL Pivot on dates column?

Tags: sql, date, boolean, pivot

I'm fairly new to SQL but believe me I have searched for help before posting this.

I have a query which returns a list of people assigned to jobs, also the jobs have varying length and people who are assigned to those jobs are working different lengths.

What I am trying to do is convert what is a list of similar records with the only variable changing is the date, and some how pivot this data so that the dates become column headings and the rows represent a BOOL yes/no.

This is the data I'm getting back currently. JSON encoded

`{"results":[{"role":"Vision Supervisor","familyname":"Unsworth","givenname":"Simon","skill":"10","level":"Telegenic Staff","id":"664","date":"2013-03-27"},{"role":"Vision Supervisor","familyname":"Unsworth","givenname":"Simon","skill":"10","level":"Telegenic Staff","id":"664","date":"2013-03-26"},{"role":"Vision Supervisor","familyname":"Unsworth","givenname":"Simon","skill":"10","level":"Telegenic Staff","id":"664","date":"2013-03-25"},{"role":"Vision Supervisor","familyname":"Unsworth","givenname":"Simon","skill":"10","level":"Telegenic Staff","id":"664","date":"2013-03-24"}]}`

and what I would like to get back is:

`{"results":[{"role":"Vision Supervisor","familyname":"Unsworth","givenname":"Simon","skill":"10","level":"Telegenic Staff","id":"664","2013-03-27":"YES","2013-03-26":"YES","2013-03-25":"YES","2013-03-24":"YES"}]}`

I'm sure this is some kind of PIVOT query but I cant get it to work.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to do this in SQL?  What rdbms are you using?  Can you post the data from the table and not in the JSON format?

Comment: Standby........Its a bit of a complicated join query.

Comment: I'm basically using php with access to remote SQL server, and then formatting in JSON to display on a iPhone app. I'cant really see an easy way to dump the database as its not managed by me.

Answer (score 21):

If you are going to be running this query in SQL Server, then you can use the `PIVOT` function:

```
select *
from
(
  select role, familyname, givenname, skill,
    level, id, date, 'Y' flag
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(flag)
  for date in ([2013-03-27], [2013-03-26],
               [2013-03-25], [2013-03-24])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da5c4/2)

Or you can use an aggregate function and a `CASE` statement:

```
select role, familyname, givenname, skill,
  level, id,
  max(case when date = '2013-03-27' then flag end) '2013-03-27',
  max(case when date = '2013-03-26' then flag end) '2013-03-26',
  max(case when date = '2013-03-25' then flag end) '2013-03-25',
  max(case when date = '2013-03-24' then flag end) '2013-03-24'
from
(
  select role, familyname, givenname, skill,
    level, id, date, 'Y' flag
  from yourtable
) src
group by role, familyname, givenname, skill,
  level, id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da5c4/3)

Both give the result:

```
|              ROLE | FAMILYNAME | GIVENNAME | SKILL |           LEVEL |  ID | 2013-03-27 | 2013-03-26 | 2013-03-25 | 2013-03-24 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Vision Supervisor |   Unsworth |     Simon |    10 | Telegenic Staff | 664 |          Y |          Y |          Y |          Y |
```

The above works great if you know the values to transpose, but you if you don't then you can use dynamic sql similar to this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(char(10), date, 120)) 
                    from yourtable
                    group by date
                    order by date desc
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT role, familyname, givenname, skill,
                    level, id,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select role, familyname, givenname, skill,
                    level, id, date, ''Y'' flag
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(flag)
                for date in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da5c4/6)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the problem was that I can't hard code the dates, they are dynamic. So I have done two queries and sorted out the results in the iPhone.

Comment: @SimonUnsworth see my edit, I added a dynamic sql version of the query

Comment: I have to do something similar again soon, I shall try the dynamic SQL. Does it work on all servers or do you need something special inserting?