# Convert Row data (Dates ) in Column headers in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

hello friends i m trying to convert row Data with dates in column headers
this is my sql attendanceData Table

Normal Table
[Original Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9GQK.png)

and i want to convert row  dates into column headers like this

Transpose
[image]

can someone tell me how i can do this in sql

i m sure using pivot i can,

so i tried sql query to pivot

```
SELECT Enterprise_ID, Date, Attendance 
FROM attendanceData natural 
    join (  SELECT Enterprise_ID 
            FROM attendanceData 
            group BY Enterprise_ID
        ) 
pivot (max(P) for Attendance in ('P' as P, 'WO' as WO)
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: i m using sql server 2012 for this

Comment: @RajendraJadhav please post the data instead of images

Comment: i have edited my question with original data as a Image link

Comment: @RajendraJadhav post the data, not images or links to images. Don't make people type your data just to test your query. The easiest you make it for people to help, the faster you'll get an answer

Comment: In any case, in `PIVOT` you specify the values you want to appear as columns. Given the desired output that would be the dates, not the categories. Those columns need to appear in the `SELECT` clause, ie `SELECT Enterprise_ID, [2018-12-12],[2018-12-13].. PIVOT (... for Date in [2018-12-13],...)` etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Pivot on dates column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977241/sql-pivot-on-dates-column)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding PIVOT function in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428993/understanding-pivot-function-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using dynamic pivot

Sample script to generate data:

```
create table #a
(
  entrprise_id varchar(50),
  datee date,
  attendance varchar(10)
)

insert into #a values
('james','2018-12-22','p'),
('james','2018-12-23','p'),
('pick','2018-12-23','p'),
('rick','2018-12-23','p'),
('pick','2018-12-22','p'),
('rick','2018-12-22','p')
```

PIVOT Query:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.datee) 
            FROM #a c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT entrprise_id, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select*
                from #A
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(attendance)
                for datee in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

or

```
select *
from
(
  select *
  from #A
) src
pivot
(
  max(attendance)
  for datee in ([2018-12-22], [2018-12-23])
) piv
```

Comment: Thanks Bro it Worked

Comment: how i can get distinct or dynamic date from date column instead of manual input  in ....max(attendance)
  for datee in ([2018-12-22], [2018-12-23])